# Is my question OK for this site?

Tags: support

I asked on SO but received nothing. Would I be more appropriate to ask this question here?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50615850/improve-movement-of-space-aliens

Comment: I think we already have a question that covers this situation. The basic idea is instead of having a named variable for each alien, instead you have a list or array of aliens, and you can check collisions against each item in the collection with a loop. If we can find the existing Q&A we'll share a link for you.

Comment: @DMGregory Great! I'm looking for something like the original space invaders algorithm, that will do.